# How to get IPv4 IP rather then loopback ip

Tags: c#, ip, loopback

I'm developing an application which needs user systems IP address for that i used below code

## Get IP

```
IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress i in localIPs)
{
    if (i.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        txtIP.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

In many systems it works very fine but some time it captures Loop-Back ip address `127.0.0.1`. Can any one guide me how can i prevent application to capture loop-back IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter the loopback IP

```
IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress i in localIPs)
{
    if (i.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork
        && !IPAddress.isLoopback(i))
    {
        txtIP.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```